# Pushing data to an analytics API

Tags: scala, error-handling

This is code that handles pushing data to an analytics API, and IMO it feels too much like Java.

`logActivity` is a method that uses `Dispatch` to POST the data to this API. I am worried that an exception could occur and that is why I wrapped the methods in a `try/catch` block. However, this feels very *Javaesque*.

Do I even need the `try/catch` block? Can `logActivity` method fail and cause the end point to stop working? Any better ways to do this?

```
  def buyLinkAnalytics(notif: Notification, reqInfo: RequestInfo): Unit = {
    try {
      logActivity(buy_link_requested, Some(LoggedInAccount(AccountId(notif.emails.get.to._id))), notif.productId.get._id.toString, None, reqInfo)
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => {
        log.error(e.toString)
      }
    }
}

  def productShareAnalytics(notif:Notification, reqInfo:RequestInfo): Unit = {
    try {
      logActivity(product_shared, Some(LoggedInAccount(AccountId(notif.emails.get.to._id))), notif.productId.get._id.toString, None, reqInfo)
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => {
        log.error(e.toString)
      }
    }
  }

  def welcomeAnalytics(notif:Notification, reqInfo:RequestInfo): Unit = {
    val uri = reqInfo.stripedUri
    try {
      logActivity(welcome, Some(LoggedInAccount(notif.accounts.get.from.get)), uri, None, reqInfo)
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => {
        log.error(e.toString)
      }
    }
  }

  def myCatalogAnalytics(notif:Notification, reqInfo:RequestInfo): Unit = {
    val uri = reqInfo.stripedUri
    try {
      logActivity(welcome, Some(LoggedInAccount(notif.accounts.get.from.get)), uri, None, reqInfo)
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => {
        log.error(e.toString)
      }
    }
  }



  def handleAnalytics(notif:Notification, reqInfo:RequestInfo) {
    notif.notification match {
      case BuyProduct => buyLinkAnalytics(notif, reqInfo)
      case ProductShare => productShareAnalytics(notif, reqInfo)
      case Welcome => welcomeAnalytics(notif, reqInfo)
      case MyCatalog => myCatalogAnalytics(notif, reqInfo)
      case _ => log.debug("Notification Type not found. Nothing put into analytics")
    }
  }


  def sendActivityLog[A] (account_id: String, activityLog: A, authParams: Map[String, String] = Map.empty[String, String], endpoint: String)(implicit fmt: Format[A]) = {
    val activityLogJson = Json.stringify (Json.toJson (activityLog))
    val scv = url(s"${config.getString("activity_log.url")}$endpoint/$account_id?key=wc_analytics") << activityLogJson <:< Map("Content-Type" -> "application/json") <:< authParams
    logger.debug(s"LOGGED: ${scv.url} << $activityLogJson")
    Http (scv OK as.String)
  }



  def logActivity (
    action      : String,
    visitor     : Option[Visitor],
    uri         : String,
    target_id   : Option[String],
    requestInfo : RequestInfo,
    context     : String = "-") = {
    import core.security.AppId.WcApp
    // In theory, no loggable business event should ever occur without an AppId.
    // But default to WC if we have to.

    val appId = requestInfo.appId.getOrElse (WcApp)._id


      val authParams = findAuthParams(requestInfo)

    if (visitor == None) {
      sendActivityLog ("None", ActivityLog (appId, action, uri, "-", context), authParams, activity_account)
    }
      visitor.foreach {
        case LoggedInAccountWithOther (account_id, other_id) =>
          sendActivityLog (
            account_id._id,
            ActivityLog (
              appId,
              action,
              uri,
              target_id.getOrElse (other_id._id),
              context
            ),
            authParams,
            activity_account
          )
        case v =>
          sendActivityLog (v.accountId._id, ActivityLog (appId, action, uri, "-", context), authParams, activity_account)
      }

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you think that those try/catch blocks look too verbose, then you can create utility method like:

```
def logExceptions[R](body: => R): R =
  try { body }
  catch {
    case e: Exception => log.error(e.toString)
  }
```

Then rewrite your code like:

```
def buyLinkAnalytics(notif: Notification, reqInfo: RequestInfo) {
  logExceptions {
    logActivity(buy_link_requested, Some(LoggedInAccount(AccountId(notif.emails.get.to._id))), notif.productId.get._id.toString, None, reqInfo)
  }
}

def productShareAnalytics(notif:Notification, reqInfo:RequestInfo) {
  logExceptions {
    logActivity(product_shared, Some(LoggedInAccount(AccountId(notif.emails.get.to._id))), notif.productId.get._id.toString, None, reqInfo)
  }
}

...
```